# Selecting strongest SIFT features for face recognition

Tags: python, image-processing, face-recognition, feature-selection, sift

I'm trying to build a python code that recognize human face. I extracted SIFT features of the training face and tested face and matching them as the following code:

```
img1 = cv2.imread("path\of\tested\image")
img2 = cv2.imread("path\of\trained\image")
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

# Brute Force Matching
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
matching_result = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches[:50], None, flags=2)
```

I want to select the strongest features among them to compare the two faces if they are of the same person or not. How can I recognize faces based on SIFT features? Can anyone please help me? any hint may be useful I'm beginner. Thanks.

Comment: Using SIFT features, one popular way is to create a Bag of Visual Words framework where you take all of the features detected from all of the faces and you create a dictionary, usually with k-Means.  Once you find these clusters, for each face you figure out which feature maps to which cluster then build a histogram.  You take these histograms and train a classification model.  This is a good place to start: https://towardsdatascience.com/bag-of-visual-words-in-a-nutshell-9ceea97ce0fb.  I'd write a complete answer for you, but I don't have access to your data.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng its a good idea, I will try to implement it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As `@rayryeng` said, a great solution would be to work with the **Bag of Visual Words/Features** approach.

The **Bag of Visual Features (BoVF)**, is inspired by the **Bag of Words (BoW)** used in the areas of **Natural Language Processing (NLP)** and **Information Retrieval (IR)** where it is applied, for example, in text categorization, where the classification of a document is given by the frequency of words.

The **Bag of Visual Features**, on the other hand, is characterized by the image categorization, where the classification of an image is given by the frequency of visual features, making it a simple and low computational cost approach.

Below I leave my codes on **GitHub** of the **Bag of Visual Features** approach with **Multilayer Perceptron (MLP)**, and **Support Vector Machine (SVM)** classifiers for **MNIST**, **CIFAR-10** and **FER-2013** visual datasets.

The cool thing about these repositories is that you can test Feature Detection and Description task, not only with Local Descriptor **SIFT**, but also with other Local Descriptors (e.g., **SURF**, **KAZE**), and Local Binary Descriptors (e.g., **BRIEF**, **ORB**, **BRISK**, **AKAZE**, **FREAK**).

- [BoVF with MLP Classifier](https://github.com/whoisraibolt/BoVF-with-MLP-Classifier)
- [BoVF with SVM Classifier](https://github.com/whoisraibolt/BoVF-with-SVM-Classifier)

I didn't put the codes directly here as it would be a too long answer.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe is the best solution, please, mark this answer as accepted! Thank you!